# phpMyAdmin: MySQL Error 1062 - Duplicate entry

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, corruption, mysql-error-1062, duplicates

I connect with user "root" onto my database "test" which I host locally for development. Among others I have the table "ratingcomment". For some reason when I click on the table "ratingcomment" phpMyAdmin shows me the following error:

```
Fehler

    SQL-Befehl: 

    INSERT INTO  `phpmyadmin`.`pma_history` (

    `username` ,
     `db` ,
     `table` ,
     `timevalue` ,
     `sqlquery`
    )
    VALUES (
    'root',  'test',  'ratingcomment', NOW( ) ,  'SELECT * FROM `ratingcomment`'
    )
    MySQL meldet: 

    #1062 - Duplicate entry '838' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

I used google to finde out the following

```
"This indicates that you have a UNIQUE or PRIMARY index on a table, and there is a duplicate value someone on one of the values in one of these indexes."
```

But I still dont quite understand the error! I use a primary Key, which auto-increments for all of my tables, so there actually shouldnt be a problem with the table. I had another table named "rating" which had a column "comment". Can it be, that this causes problems?

Comment: What is the primary for the table? Query record with primary key 838 and see compare the values to the values you are attempting to `INSERT`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quick fix:

```
REPAIR TABLE `phpmyadmin`.`pma_history`
```

If that fails, I'd just truncate/empty the table.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `phpmyadmin`.`pma_history`
```

Although phpmyadmin has it's place in my toolbox, I personally don't use it's internal db.

**ADDENDUM**

MyISAM tables can easily become corrupted. A couple causes that usually hit me: if the MySQL is not shutdown properly, or if the table has a FULLTEXT index and the stopword file on disk had changed.

Simply stated, the `REPAIR` just checkes the data file for errors (and depending on your options, makes it usable again) and rewrites the index file. Fair warning: with MyISAM, repairing a table can often toast all your data in that table to make it `usable`. See [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/repair-table.html) for more details.

A google search pertaining to this pma table being corrupted lead me to [this](http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=32520).

Comment: Thanks: Repair Table worked! But I dont quite understand what happened, why I needed to repair the table, and what repair table actually does! I would appreciate a small description and/or some links that explain the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an internal error. You've issued this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `ratingcomment`
```

phpMyAdmin tries to write such action in its internal event log and it fails. If you Google for `pma_history` you'll find several references to such table being corrupted.

My advice is that you find another SQL client (such as HeidiSQL) and try to repair the phpMyAdmin database.

Comment: I'd appreciate some feedback about the downvote, considering that I basically say the same as the accepted answer.

Comment: This is correct, because what happened on my end was our MySQL Database crashed or something, so it could be that the tables are corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kinda late but I had the same problem and wanted to share what I did.

In PhpMyAdmin, I went to the table's Operation tab, and just incremented the AUTO_INCREMENT value under Table options and inserted a dummy record.